# Algorithm problem: find minimum number of trips to ship all packages

Tags: algorithm, optimization

There are `n` packages to ship from one city to another city, denoted by:
`int nums[n]`,
where `nums[i]` is the weight (in kilos) of ith package.

For example:
`nums = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8].`

There's a truck of capacity `K` in kilos. For example: `int K = 9.`

Return the minimum number of trips needed to ship all packages.

For the given example, the result should be: `3` trips. And:

trip 1:
`[1, 8]`

trip 2:
`[2, 7]`

trip 3:
`[1, 3, 4]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Show us what have you done so far.

Comment: This is the optimization variant of [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). Once you know the name of it, you could probably find a lot of resources how to solve it, and why is it hard to do so for all cases. Good luck!

Comment: @amit Amit, thank you very much for pointing this out. Now I know what to look up. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I would have a look at a *backtracking* solution.

Comment: ```sum(nums)/k``` would be the lower bound. You can then use optimisation to figure out the number of trips that satisfies the constraints